# What is the logic behind the isset() function in PHP?

Tags: php, isset

I accidentally experience this issue when I was writing code in one of my application.

```
$ar = [
   'first' => 1,
   'second' => 2,
   ......
];
```

when I tried to check that index in `$array` which doesn't exist

```
if(isset($ar['third']) && !empty($ar['third'])){
    echo "Found";
}else{
    echo "Not Found";
}
```

It worked without error as expected, but when I put this conditions in the common function and then checked

```
function sanitize($value){
   if(isset($value) && !empty($value)){
       return true;
   }else{
       return false;
   }
}

if(sanitize($ar['third'])){
   echo "Found";
}else{
   echo "Not Found";
}
```

Above sample throws an exception undefined index error, can someone explain why this is causing the error.

Comment: This said, this question is a simple typo.

Comment: 1. `sanitize` is a bad name for this function, since it doesn't "sanitise" anything. Just saying, hope it's just an example. 2. `isset && !empty` is redundant. 3. If `$ar['third']` doesn't exist here: `sanitize($ar['third'])`, you can't have any expectation that code *inside* the function will suppress that error.

Comment:  [The Definitive Guide To PHP's isset And empty](http://kunststube.net/isset/)

Comment: @deceze yes it's just an example

Comment: The key thing to remember is that  `isset` is not a function, but a special language construct. Since its purpose is to detect variables, array elements, or object properties which are uninitialized, it bypasses the normal check that would raise a Notice. But in your code, the Notice *was already raised* before the `isset` line is reached, so it's too late for it to suppress the check.

Answer (score 1):

`$value` is always set because it is declared as a function parameter so it always exists. So in this case using `isset()` is pointless.

```
function sanitize($value){ // <-- Variable is declared so it exists 
                           // within the scope of this function
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to refer to the `$ar` array at that the '`third`' index before the isset/empty check is actually executed (as that is within the `sanitise` function).

PHP is therefore showing the error for the `if(sanitize($ar['third'])){` line.